# subtraction of pointers variable in arrays in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()  
   {   
      int arr[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};      
      int *i,*j,*k;     
      k=2686703;     
      i=&arr[1];     
      j=&arr[5];           
      printf("%d\n%d\n",i,j)  ;        
      printf("%d\n",j-i);        
      printf("%d",*(k));  
      return 0;
   }
```

output :

```
 2686700  
 2686716  
 garbage value
```

why is the difference between j and i =4 and not 16 ?  If 4 bytes are reserved for each integer in an array why is their garbage value corrosponding to this intermediate address ?

Comment: please clarify your problem and your sample. For instance, printf("%d\n%d\n",j-i) is wrong as you only have one var to display. I understand that you are trying to understand how pointers to an array work, but the question and the sample are unclear (and the sample contains "absolute" value k=2686703 that can not be used elsewhere

Comment: how can you assign `k=2686703; `? here k is pointer

Comment: The integer type in the format string is also wrong. A pointer subtraction results in a ptrdiff_t value, which may be printed as %td (assuming C99/C11, C89 will need a cast)

Answer (score 2):

> why is the difference between j and i =4 and not 16 and if 4 bytes are reserved for each integer in an array

Because this is how pointer arithmetic works: it divides `sizeof(element)` out of the difference. This simplifies programming with pointers a lot, because it is easier for programmers to think of offsets in terms of array elements, rather than raw bytes.

> why is the garbage value corrosponding to this intermediate address

You dereference pointer `k`, which is assigned a value that is not aligned with any of the integers. Generally speaking, this is undefined behavior. In your case, however, you picked a value that happens to point to the middle of the array. Depending on the system, the result could be anything - from crashing due to an unaligned read to re-interpreting valid bytes as a different integer.